# I am getting this error while installing prometheus operator in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, helm3

This chart is deprecated
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to install CRD crds/crd-alertmanager.yaml: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Comment: What is your k8s version? `$ kubectl version --short`?  also add the command you used to deploy the chart.

Comment: sudo helm install prometheus monitor/prometheus-operator --namespace prometheus

Comment: minikube version --v1.25.1         kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.1
Server Version: v1.23.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> helm install prometheus monitor/prometheus-operator --namespace prometheus

The chart `prometheus-operator` is deprecated!

Deprecation message:

```
DEPRECATED

This chart will be renamed, but first must be deprecated before the prometheus-community/helm-charts repo is indexed, so that it won't be listed in the hubs. See [this prometheus-community issue](https://github.com/prometheus-community/community/issues/28#issuecomment-670406329) for reasoning and next steps.
```

Try the latest one:

```sh
$ helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
$ helm repo update
$ helm install kube-prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace prometheus
```

**N.B.:** The `apiVersion` for [custom resource definitions (CRD)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/) is `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1` now.